# Tablespace and userid info

Tags: oracle

I have to create some scripts to create a new and empty DB ready for a new install of our apps on a new server.

I am easily getting the tables, views etc info from SQL Developers Export facility (without the data of course), but I have a problem where I need to define the userid and the TableSpace.

I realise these are quite straight forward, but what I would like to know is how the original ones are defined on our current DB, as the original scripts (and info) are no longer available, and I need to make sure I create them correctly with the new scripts.

So how do I display all the required info for a userid and for a TableSpace so that I can use this info in the create commands in the scripts ?

It may be helpful for you to know this is my first attempt at scripting and only my 2nd attempt at and interfacing with Oracle, so I have limited knowledge in this field, hence the simple request. :)

Any help or advice would be most appreciated.

Cheers, George.

Comment: You should store all scripts to create all your database objects in a version control system. Then you just replay them on the new server. You should really consider doing that once you have extracted everything.

Comment: I agree, this important info should always be available. I will make sure it is all stored when I am finished this small project.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [`DBMS_METADATA`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_metada.htm) package. First set `long` to some big number so the output isn't truncated, and set the SQL terminator so you can see how statements are separated:

```
SQL> set long 30000
SQL> exec dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.SESSION_TRANSFORM,'SQLTERMINATOR',TRUE);
```

To get the tablespace (substitute your own for `USERS` of course):

```
SQL> select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLESPACE', 'USERS') from dual;

DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLESPACE','USERS')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLESPACE "USERS" DATAFILE
  '/home/oracle/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/users01.dbf' SIZE 5242880
  AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 1310720 MAXSIZE 32767M
  LOGGING ONLINE PERMANENT BLOCKSIZE 8192
  EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL AUTOALLOCATE DEFAULT NOCOMPRESS  SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT AUTO;
   ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE
  '/home/oracle/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/users01.dbf' RESIZE 256901120;
```

You'll probably need to modify the datafile path for the new server. To get the user:

```
SQL> select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('USER', 'SCOTT') from dual;

DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('USER','SCOTT')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE USER "SCOTT" IDENTIFIED BY VALUES 'S:64F10A7102E73EFFAC1BE155794F1E8DA6C8F948A5713D5D5EC462AA0382;4DD35D67F0372586'
      DEFAULT TABLESPACE "USERS"
      TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "TEMP";
```

Then you need the grants the user has. Depending on your actual user some of these may not return anything:

```
SQL> select dbms_metadata.get_granted_ddl('SYSTEM_GRANT', 'SCOTT') from dual;

DBMS_METADATA.GET_GRANTED_DDL('SYSTEM_GRANT','SCOTT')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  GRANT CHANGE NOTIFICATION TO "SCOTT";
  GRANT DROP ANY DIRECTORY TO "SCOTT";
  GRANT CREATE ANY DIRECTORY TO "SCOTT";
  GRANT CREATE DATABASE LINK TO "SCOTT";
  GRANT CREATE VIEW TO "SCOTT";
  GRANT CREATE SYNONYM TO "SCOTT";
  GRANT CREATE TABLE TO "SCOTT";
  GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO "SCOTT";
  GRANT ALTER SESSION TO "SCOTT";


SQL> select dbms_metadata.get_granted_ddl('ROLE_GRANT', 'SCOTT') from dual;

DBMS_METADATA.GET_GRANTED_DDL('ROLE_GRANT','SCOTT')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   GRANT "CONNECT" TO "SCOTT";
   GRANT "RESOURCE" TO "SCOTT";
   GRANT "XFILES_USER" TO "SCOTT";


SQL> select dbms_metadata.get_granted_ddl('OBJECT_GRANT', 'SCOTT') from dual;

DBMS_METADATA.GET_GRANTED_DDL('OBJECT_GRANT','SCOTT')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  GRANT EXECUTE ON "SYS"."DBMS_LOCK" TO "SCOTT";
  GRANT EXECUTE ON "SYS"."DBMS_CRYPTO" TO "SCOTT";
  GRANT EXECUTE, READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY "SO_DIR" TO "SCOTT";
```

You can use the same functions to get your table and view scripts if you prefer - I believe SQL Developer's export uses them under the hood anyway - and to get role definitions and grants.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for this, its exactly what I was looking for. Perhaps you can answer a further question pls/ I tried to create a new userid but there was a PASSWORD-VERIFY_FUNCTION listed and it couldnt find the "user_function". I tried to look up the "function" in the same way you have listed but it could not find it on the current system, so I dont know how to add this fuctions I have no idea whats in it. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @Haglis - you should be able to see it like this, but maybe it's in a different schema (which you can specify with the third parameter to `get_ddl`)? Can you see it in `dba_objects`? Also check you're using the right case for the function name.

Comment: Alex, I am not sure what you mean by can I see it in dba_objects ?

Comment: @Haglis - `select owner, object_type, object_name from dba_objects where object_type = 'FUNCTION' and lower(object_name) = 'user_function'` will show if the function exists, which schema owns it, and if you're using the wrong case.

Comment: It doest come back with anything other than the headings.

Comment: @Haglis - that sounds odd, I'm not aware of any clients that would present headings when there's no data. Anyway, I think you should ask about finding and extracting this function as a new question, including the reference you got from the user DDL and any queries you ran with their output.

Answer (score 1):

An option that can be interesting for this type of thing is to use `expdp`/`impdp` to get all the metadata from your source database *en masse*.

You'd do this by, for example:

1. Running a full export of your source database's metadata
2. Doing a few `SQLFILE`-mode imports, which don't actually import anything but generates SQL scripts for the objects you're interested in.

You can filter by schema for instance, and use most of the options `expdp` and `impdp` have to customize the SQL, and modify it if you need to before using it.

#### Sample usage:

```
expdp user/*** directory=EXPORT_DIR dumpfile=metadata.dmp \
               full=Y content=METADATA_ONLY exclude=STATISTICS
```

This will export all your database's metadata to `metadata.dmp` (provided you've created the `EXPORT_DIR` directory in the database), excluding statistics information (I'm assuming you're not going to reload the same data, so the source statistics are irrelevant).

For tablespace definitions:

```
impdp user/*** directory=EXPORT_DIR sqlfile=tablespaces.sql \
               include=TABLESPACE
```

To generate a table and index creation SQL script (`tables.sql`):

```
impdp user/*** directory=EXPORT_DIR sqlfile=tables.sql \
               include=TABLE schemas=USER1,USER2,USER3
```

To generate user and grant creation script:

```
impdp user/*** directory=EXPORT_DIR sqlfile=users.sql \
               include=USER,GRANT schemas=USER1,USER2,USER3
```

This is pretty handy if you want to script the process outside the database (the generated SQL is very regular, so *relatively* safe to reprocess). If you want to script the process in PL/SQL, `DBMS_METADATA` is definitely the way to go as [Alex Poole's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/25880/2808) describes.

Comment: Thanks for this info too, we will need to export/import in the future too which will also make me nervous ! :)